# AUCTeX: How to toggle between \( \) and \[ \]

Tags: equations, emacs, auctex

I have TeX-electric-math[1] set to replace `$` with `\(` and `\)` for inline equations. In the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html)[2] it claims that repeatedly pressing `$` while in the active math region, you can toggle between inline `\(...\)` and display `\[...\]` equations, but this seems to simply not work (I just get `\($\)`). Am I misunderstanding, or is there something I still need to configure for this to work?

[1] `'(TeX-electric-math (quote ("\\(" . "\\)")))`

This was generated using the Emacs customization menus

[2] https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html

Last paragraph under Dollar Signs -> TeX-electric-math

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select a region that isn't in math mode, and press `$`: the first time you'll wrap it with inline math delimiters (e.g. `\(...\)`or `$...$`), the second time it'll be replaced by display math delimiters (e.g. `\[...\]` or `$$...$$`). This how it's supposed to work.